# Has anyone earned the Invincible or Jitterbug achievements in Mega Man 9?

Tags: achievements, mega-man-9

My son was playing *[Mega Man 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man_9)* this afternoon and it reminded me of its [insane in-game achievments](http://www.1up.com/news/hardcore-mega-man-9-achievements), the two most extreme being:

- **Invincible**: Clear the game without dying.
- **Jitterbug**: Clear the game in 60 minutes or less.

**Has anyone ever earned these achievements?**  Is there any proof (e.g., video, etc).

Comment: I found this list of the achievements at giantbomb: http://www.giantbomb.com/mega-man-9/61-20975/achievements/ so it looks like at least some folks are trying for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the XBLA version goes, yes, a few people have earned it. Microsoft doesn't have anywhere publicly available that lists full numbers of how many people have acquired achievements (that I've ever seen or heard of), but 2 sites that I use show them for anyone who has registered. Their stats are pulled from users public Xbox profiles which is the best proof I can give.

**Jitterbug**

- [TrueAchievements Users](http://www.trueachievements.com/achievementgamer.aspx?achievementid=26468) - 681 of their tracked users who have the game (26%)
- [GiantBomb Users](http://www.giantbomb.com/achievements/jitterbug/96189/) - 123 users w/ game (4.7%)

**Invincible**

- [TrueAchievements Users](http://www.trueachievements.com/achievementgamer.aspx?achievementid=26469) - 579 users w/ game (22%)
- [GiantBomb Users](http://www.giantbomb.com/achievements/invincible/96188/) - 97 users w/ game (3.7%)

Comment: I… can't… believe… it. Talk about mad skills. I am shamed and fear to ever pick up a controller again.

Comment: Indeed, lots of skill, patience and extra controllers to throw.